# C# : update data in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms

```
string con = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kavindu yasintha\Documents\billmangment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
string q = "SELECT * FROM member";

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(q, con);

SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(ad);
DataSet set = new DataSet();
        
ad.Update(set.Tables["member"]);
ad.Fill(set, "member");

dataGridView1.DataSource = set.Tables["member"];

MessageBox.Show("Updated");
```

How to solve this? I want to update my data gridview. How to add this code and what is this error?

Comment: It is not clear what is your problem. Didn't you see your DataGridView filled with data? Or do you want to save the changes made into the DataGridView to your database table?

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` has an [`UpdateCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) property, you should set that with a parameterized sql update statement.

Comment: https://github.com/kavindyasinthasilva/Nsbm-Assingment-Online-canteen-system

Comment: i want change DataGridview .

Comment: There is no need to call `ad.Update()`. When you reset the DataSource, the original will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to update the source of your datagridview.
I made some adjustment in your code and the use of datatable.
You might consider this approach.

```
string con = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kavindu yasintha\Documents\billmangment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
string q = "SELECT * FROM member";

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(q, con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ad.Fill(dt);
   
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;   
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

MessageBox.Show("Updated");
```